# console.group not working in JS snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I want to use [`console.group/groupEnd`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#consolegroupobject_object) in a snippet, but calls to them seem to be ignored.

```js
console.group("my group");
console.log("foo");
console.groupEnd();
```

Comment: It might be that the console logging is still nascent and this use case hasn't been fully explored.

Comment: Those calls still work in your dev console, by the way. Just not in the snippet console. Same for `console.table`.

Comment: `console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` and
`console.dir([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` produces the same results as well.

Comment: I don't think it is meant to be a full featured console. If it were, they would just throw firebug lite in there and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.js

The only methods supported by the snippet console are

- `console.log`
- `console.warn`
- `console.info`
- `console.error`
- `console.assert`
- `console.dir`
- `console.clear`
- `console.time`
- `console.timeEnd`
- `console.config`

Other method calls will be only native (if supported by the browser).

Some months ago I also proposed some improvement to the snippet console, I even provided the code. But it seems the team has no interest in improving it. I consider it feature-frozen.

Comment: I actually started rewriting the whole console in order to sandbox the console display from the demo DOM, communicating with everything via `postMessage()`. `console.table()` and `console.group()` are among several commands I added. I also started true parsing of format strings along with various other display improvements. I don't know... there's a lot in there and a lot left to do. So, it's not done -been busy... and it'll take some dev time on the SO side to change how they launch snippets -if they even decide it's worth it.

Comment: @canon No problem. You could start by merging [pr #1](https://github.com/gh-canon/stack-snippet-console/pull/1) :D

Comment: oh, god... those are leftovers from when I was invoking `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` back through the prototype chain to get _everything_.... not just enumerable properties.